# MS Access - Search criteria by month

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a month & year search criteria for the below SQL code.  I'm making an MS Access app that lets the user choose the company - which I've done.  Then let's the user choose the month & year then the user clicks ok and get's the info for the filtered month along with 2 prior months.  I know this is a lot, but I've had no luck with the date filter.  I've followed all kinds of examples, but I can't seem to get my head around it.  Can someone please help me out with a code example or something similar.  Thanks so much

Here's the SQL code:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.MARKET_VALUE) AS SumOfMARKET_VALUE
SELECT [dbo_FIRM]![NAME] AS [FIRM NAME], dbo_FUND.CUSIP, dbo_FUND.FUND_NAME,dbo_FUND.PRODUCT_NAME                                     
FROM (dbo_ASSET_HISTORY INNER JOIN dbo_FIRM ON dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.FIRM_ID = dbo_FIRM.FIRM_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_FUND ON dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.FUND = dbo_FUND.FUND
WHERE (((dbo_FIRM.NAME) Like "Voya F*") AND     ((dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.ASSET_YEAR)=Year(DateAdd('m',-1,Date()))) AND     ((dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.ASSET_MONTH) In (Month(DateAdd('m',-1,Date())))))
GROUP BY [dbo_FIRM]![NAME], dbo_FUND.CUSIP, dbo_FUND.FUND_NAME, dbo_FUND.PRODUCT_NAME
PIVOT [dbo_ASSET_HISTORY]![ASSET_YEAR] & '-' & [dbo_ASSET_HISTORY]!    [ASSET_MONTH];
```

Here's a piece of VBA
This was only for the "month filter" just as a test to see if it works

```
Dim adjust As String
Dim task As String

Private Sub Command0_Click()
If IsNull(Me.month_filt) Then
    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "ct_VoysF_AUM_Q"
Else
    adjust = "(ASSET_MONTH >= #" & Me.month_filt & "# AND ASSET_MONTH <= #"    & Me.month_filt & "#)"
    task = "Select * from ct_VoysF_AUM_Q where (" & adjust & ")"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks wrong to me: "# AND ASSET_MONTH <= #"  - remove the AND from the date string.

Comment: Thx Ron, I've tried that.  Doesn't really work.  I know the syntax is totally off, that's why I'm looking for a correct example of how to do this.  Thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are matching a month to a month, you do not use the # - this is only for dates:

```
adjust = "(ASSET_MONTH >= " & Me.month_filt & " AND #ASSET_MONTH <= " & Me.month_filt & ")"
```

only 
OR

```
adjust = "(ASSET_MONTH BETWEEN " & Me.month_filt & " AND " & Me.month_filt & ")"
```

Comment: Glad I could help, Alvin.